# how to display uploaded file in profile

Tags: drupal, custom-fields, profile

I have a civi profile with a custom field where contacts upload their student ID, this works fine, however I can't find a way to display the uploaded file in the profile itself ie: when something is already uploaded it should be visible in the profile form, any ideas? Thanks in advance